# errores 404 en aplicacion Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

tengo una pagina, que a pesar que funciona correctamente, al entrar al debugger de crome (ctrl+shift+P) me marca errores de recurso no encontrado 404

sin embargo, las carpetas y los recursos se encuentran disponibles y bie direccionados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a que se puede deber este error? y como puedo solucionarlo?

aca pongo una foto del proyect mvc en VS2015

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De inicio, te recomendaría tener las referencias a estilos desde el archivo `App_Start\BundlesConfig.cs`. Ahora, las referencias las debes poner que busquen desde la carpeta raíz con el caracter `~`, te va a quedar algo así:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/css").Include(
    "~/css/style_base.css",         
    "~/css/estilo_carro.css"
));
```

De momento, para asegurarte que funcione, solo agrega el caracter `~` al inicio:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style_base.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/estilo_carro.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, no me habia percatado de que me faltaba ese caracter.. Ya esta solucionado. Voy a tomar tu sugerencia acerca de utilizar app_start\bundlesconfig.cs. Gracias

Comment: Cuando agregues las referencias al BundlesConfig.cs y te surjan dudas recuerda que puedes preguntarlo y de igual forma vemos la forma de echarlo a andar :D